# Search for string to move one row lower

Tags: excel, vba

Sheet contains commission data for employees.
Data is dumped out of Accounting system each week.
Need to move a cell value "Totals" down 1 row to align with the relevant data.

Have tried to search for the string "Totals" then cut and paste 1 row lower.

The string is in col-A.  The dataset size and content rows is variable each week but the target string is always in col-A and needs to drop down 1 row, probably with an offset (1, 0) style of command?

```vb
Dim m As Integer
m = 2
    
Do Until m = 300 'this is set to cover the expected occurrences
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Range(A1, A300).Cells("m", 0).Find(What:="Totals").Offset(1, 0) = "TOTALS"
    m = m + 1
    On Error GoTo 0

Loop
```

Getting no error messages but no results either!

Comment: "Getting no error msgs" - maybe remove `On Error Resume Next` and fix the ones you see?

Comment: Other there other headers, other than "Totals" that you are trying to align the "Totals" with?

Answer (score 0):

Forget the 'Cut & Paste'. Simply insert a new row at the 'Totals' row.

```
dim m as variant

m = application.match("totals", range("A:A"), 0)

if not iserror(m) then

    rows(m).insert

end if
```

(and YES you should qualify your parent worksheets!)

Comment: Inserting a row will shift ALL headers down.If there are other headers that aren't "Totals" this will interfere.

Comment: @Dean
OK thanks for replies all - have realized that my original post may have been unclear on the structure of the accounting data source so I will try to include this below. 
Link to my sample data format here.

[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/du230n6l5tl8gbv/TOTALS.png?dl=0).

Hope this helps and I havn't broken a stack of stackoverflow rules?

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I think you are after. Define the range where the "Totals" lie - assuming they are in a Row? See below code.

```
Sub LoopTotals()

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim myRange As Range

    'set the range
    Set myRange = Sheet1.Range("A1:AA1")

    'loop through range
    For Each cell In myRange
        'check if text is "Totals"
        If Trim(cell.Text) = "Totals" Then
            'set the new "Totals" 1 row lower
            cell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "Totals"
            'delete the old string value
            cell.ClearContents
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Additionally, if the "Totals" are pulled in differently each time from the accounting software then you can run a search to find the "Totals" and then you can reference that row number for you range.